# Need help identifying power potential of a circuit

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, capacitor, circuit-design, motor-controller

[image]

This unit is an ESC for a brushless motor. I need to know the maximum voltage it can handle; I keep blowing 25V, 2200μF capacitors while trying to run 48V on it.

Secondly, what capacitors should I replace these with in order to accommodate 48V?

Comment: your question cannot be answered without a schematic diagram of the circuit

Comment: Why would you *not* expect to blow 25 volt rated capacitors when you expose them to 48 volts?

Comment: Changing the caps to 68 V rated caps will not guarantee that you can apply 48 V because there may be something else that will fail at 48 V (such as MOSFET's or MOSFET driver IC or some other IC like a high voltage LDO generating VCC for the logic, etc).

Comment: I thought that 4 25v caps in series would allow up to 100v.

Comment: @RichardPhillips *Are* the caps in series? They could very well be in parallel, or decoupling four distinct nets.

Comment: I would assume they are in parallel. I have never seen anyone put big electrolytic caps like that in series in an ESC. You have to de-rate the voltage if they are in series because the voltage across each cap is dependent on the actual capacitance.

Comment: I'm not actually sure. The esc is supposed to run on 12v power with a 5v trigger wire for on/off but the actual motor can be ran off of a separate power source. I have no idea. I'm not much of an engineer but I can replace the caps well enough. So, if these are in parallel, then running 23v should be ok? That would allow the +- of 2 tolerance.

Comment: NOTE: The 12v power wire I mentioned is just to turn the unit on. It has separate power wires for the "Main".

Comment: @RichardPhillips You're able to see things (like the circuit board) that we can't from behind our screen, so you're in a better position to determine if the caps are in series/parallel. Knowing nothing about this board, and just knowing what the common practices are, they're probably in parallel.

Comment: Sometimes motors are noisy because of sudden current spikes etc. Maybe 23 V is a bit too high for 25 V capacitors when you consider the noise and spikes. But you can try it and see what happens as long as you have extra ESC's available. I think a common theme is emerging that you are just going to have to experiment. Nobody can answer the questions you are asking without a lot more information. I don't suppose you have some kind of documentation for the ESC or a link to where you bought it? Anything?

Comment: Ok, I got some more information. This circuit basically works like this, there is a 12v master "on" wire that tells the esc to turn on. Then, there is a 1v-5v trigger wire that tells the esc to "turn on throttle". Then the trigger wire opens a flood gate to another set of power wires that actually power the motor. This unit might be meant for 12v-16v only but I need to rebuild this circuit to work with atleast 24v. I have more photos but the website won't allow me to "add photo" the button does nothing. Thank all of you so much for your help and consideration.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/gallery/H5xV6Lj

Answer (score 1):

Obtain about 5 ESC's. Take out all the big 25 V caps in one of them. Slowly ramp up the voltage while monitoring the input current. Don't try to spin any motors. Just increase the voltage and note the current. When you see a dramatic increase in current, something else has failed. That is your absolute maximum voltage. You can probably use about 75% - 80% of that as your operating voltage. Put in new big caps rated for your new absolute maximum voltage and give it a try.

If you find something else blows up, then go back down by 5 V until you find the true maximum allowable working voltage that doesn't cause anything to blow up.

OR you could just ask the manufacturer, or you could try to find a schematic. Or you could just buy an ESC that is rated for the voltage you want to use.